# Is there a way to search sameness in an array with bash without loop?

Tags: bash, loops, if-statement

So I have an array with strings, and another string variable itself, and I want to do a process, when the variable is one of the element of the array. Can it be write an IF line, without checking all elements with a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash now supports associative arrays, that is arrays which keys are strings:

```
declare -A my_associative_array
```

So, you could maybe turn your classical array into an associative one and get access to the entry you are looking for with a simple:

```
my_string="foo bar"
my_associative_array["$my_string"]="baz cux"
echo "${my_associative_array[$my_string]}"
echo "${my_associative_array[foo bar]}"
```

And to test the existence of a key:

```
if [ "${my_associative_array[$my_string]:+1}" ]; then
  echo yes;
else
  echo no;
fi
```

From bash manual:

```
   ${parameter:+word}
          Use Alternate Value.  If parameter is null or unset, nothing
          is substituted, otherwise the expansion of word is substituted.
```

So, if the key `$my_string` is null or unset, `${my_associative_array[$my_string]:+1}` expands to nothing, else to `1`. The rest is just a classical use of the `if` bash statement combined with `test` (`[]`):

```
if [ 1 ]; then echo true; else echo false; fi
```

prints `true` while:

```
if [ ]; then echo true; else echo false; fi
```

prints `false`. If you prefer to consider null entries as any other existing entry, just omit the colon:

```
if [ "${my_associative_array[$my_string]+1}" ]; then
  echo yes;
else
  echo no;
fi
```

From bash manual:

```
          Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter
          that is unset.
```

Comment: Could you write an example to the checking too, please?